# Add New Role in AspNetRoles Table Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How to **Add New Role** in **AspNetRoles** Table in **Identity**?

```
var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "Admin");
```

I am using the above code to assign **Admin** role to the user, but it throws an error

> **"Role Admin does not exist."**

I have tried to Add Role in **AspNetRoles** Table directly in the SQL, but failed.

Can anyone please tell me how to add **New Role** in **AspNetRoles** Table Using **Code**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Add the Role `Admin` first before adding the User to the Role:

```
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context); //Pass the instance of your DbContext here
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
```

Create the Role `Admin`:

```
roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
```

Then add your User:

```
UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "Admin");
```