# InvalidOperationException: Role ADMIN does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a registration system with roles to view data with limitations in my
Asp.Net core project using Identity so I got this error and I'll appreciate it if someone guides me to solutions ............................

```
InvalidOperationException: Role ADMIN does not exist.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TUserToken, TRoleClaim>.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string normalizedRoleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
Relog.Controllers.AccountController.Register(AppUser model) in AccountController.cs
-
                    Email = model.Email
                };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password );
                if(result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
```

this is Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Relog.Data;
using Relog.Models;
//using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppUserDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
//builder.Services.AddDbContext<StockDbContext>(options =>
//    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppUserDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppUserDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{


    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

});

app.Run();
```

this is AccountController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Relog.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Relog.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;

        }



        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task  <IActionResult> Register(AppUser model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = model.FirstName + model.LastName,
                    Email = model.Email
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password );
                if(result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Register!");
                return View(model);
            }

            return View("Register", model);

        }
    }
}
```

this is my Dbcontext file

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Relog.Models;


namespace Relog.Data
{
    public class AppUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppUserDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppUserDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<IdentityUser>();
        }


        public DbSet<Relog.Models.AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

my model :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Relog.Models
{
    public class AppUser
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(150)")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(150)")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }



        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }



        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }



        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you insert the role "Admin" into the database? Check the `AspNetRoles` table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add New Role in AspNetRoles Table Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63730538/add-new-role-in-aspnetroles-table-identity)

Answer (score 3):

Okay! I found a solution by the help of [Tiny Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14574199/tiny-wang) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562143/18773264), the issue's solution is To add the **NormalizedName** in the **Roles** table (UpperCase letters) instead of NULL! You can do that manually or using the above piece of code of Tiny Wang

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue description, it's missing "admin" role in the role table.

before the line-code `await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");` you need to add business logic, like what @klekmek commented, write code to check if there's Admin role in the table, code snippet from [this high vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42472760).

```
var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
if (!roleExist)
{
    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
}
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

add rolemanager to accountcontroller

```
 private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
 public AccountController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
 {    
   _roleManager = roleManager;
 }
```

after the model data is inserted add this business logic, you need to add a role in the AspNetRoles table.

```
if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("admin").GetAwaiter().GetResult())
{
  await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("admin"));
  await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("customer"));
  //multiple role add
}
```

in this logic, if your table doesn't have an admin and customer role,then identity automatically creates a role.